# Definition of Coulomb

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge

It is written in a book that theoretically we are unable to get the definition of *' **Coulomb** '* from **Coulomb's law of electrostatic force between two charges** . But it can only be explained by **electro-magnetism** .
**Why?**

Comment: Which book? Which page?

Comment: are you asking abut the SI base unit being the ampere, and not the coloumb.

Comment: Ok , let's take that . What'll be the answer then.

Comment: Search the site. It's been asked many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *official definition* of the coulomb in the current [9th Edition of the International System of Units](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/) (SI), as published on the website of the International Bureau of Weights and Measures (BIPM), is that it is an ampere-second.

The coulomb is a *derived* unit, not a *base* unit. The *ampere* is the electromagnetic base unit in SI. It was this way in the 8th Edition, and it remains so in the 9th; what changed is how the *ampere* is defined.

Somewhat bizarrely, the ampere is now defined in a way that makes the elementary charge $e$ be an exact quantity in coulombs, but this is *not* used as the official *definition* of the coulomb. It seems roundabout, and it is. I will leave it to a metrologist to explain why.

As for your book’s claim, it is incorrect. The current definitions of the coulomb and the ampere have nothing to do with magnetism. However, the old definition of the ampere did involve magnetism. Previously, defining the ampere through magnetostatics rather than the coulomb through electrostatics was a historical choice with no theoretical necessity. It probably allowed more precise metrology.

By contrast with SI’s coulomb, the statcoulomb in Gaussian units has always been defined using Coulomb’s Law: two point charges of one statcoulomb separated by one centimeter have a repulsion of one dyne. For historical reasons, electromagnetic SI units are much less elegant than Gaussian ones. Gaussian units don’t even require a separate base unit for charge, current, or anything else electromagnetic. All Gaussian units for EM quantities can simply be defined in terms of length, time, and mass, and mysterious constants like $\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$ are completely unnecessary.